# Writing to onboard video memory on x86 architecture?

Tags: video, graphics, hardware

I want to test out my real hardware by writing directly to the onboard video hardware.

How do I do that?

This is for my own OS project, and it has to be for my onboard graphics directly, not any `nVidia` card or such.

Comment: A better question would potentially be ... how do I find out what the instructions set, specifications, and architecture is of my onboard device, and what kind it is?

Comment: Check out [OSDev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page). There's plenty there that should help you figure this out. In particular, [Drawing In Protected Mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/Drawing_In_Protected_Mode).

Comment: @Mac I don't have a video card I have only onboard video hardware.

Comment: The page I linked to talks about VGA/VESA graphics modes, same as @EricJ mentions in his answer. As he mentions, you can be certain that if your onboard graphics is any newer than about 20 years old it will support VGA as a minimum, and almost certainly support VESA.

Comment: @Mac But I want to access video memory without BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

You can write directly to memory addresses standardized for EGA/VGA starting at the address

> A000:0000

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array#Addressing_details

Mode X allows for somewhat higher resolutions than supported by the VGA standard on VGA compatible hardware.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array#Programming_tricks

If your BIOS supports VESA, you can use VESA BIOS calls to setup extended video modes

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions

There is a detailed introduction to VESA programming (even a summary would be too extensive to include in an answer here) that provides pretty much everything you need to get started programming with VESA modes

http://www.monstersoft.com/tutorial1/VESA_intro.html

Comment: How do I know if there's EGA/VGA support on my motherboard?

Comment: Also, setting up a video mode from VESA BIOS would still not give me the exact instruction set of the device itself.

Comment: @Write_To_Onboard_Video_ If your motherboard is newer than about 1990, it will provide EGA/VGA support.  VESA is a newer standard, and even that standard was broadly implemented by the mid to late 90s.

Comment: @Write_To_Onboard_Video_: Added a link to a detailed tutorial on accessing memory from a VESA mode.

Comment: So you're saying that VESA would be the primary onboard hardware specification for graphics, considering I have no external GPU/card?

Comment: Any graphic adapter you have in this day and age should support VESA, whether integrated or external.